# Janus in Kubernetes failed in ICE connectivity, while in docker it works

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, janus-gateway

I tried to deploy janus in k8 cluster. The design looks like

**Internet <----> Nginx on 443,Forwarding to ClusterIP Port 8088 <--> Janus-Service Port Map <----> Janus Pod**

I am able to access Janus over https://domain-name.com/janus/info and it prints the complete information on browser.

When I start video recording, the ICE connectivity fails due to IP of pod in SDP which is not accessible from outside. Also, I tried with nat_1_1 mapping and put the public IP address of Nginx Load Balancer, but result is same.

I suspect the RTP ports mapping are required on nginx deployment.

Can someone give a clue how to make it working.

The docker is working perfectly and there is no ICE failure at all.

I have no clue how to map such a large number of ports in kubernetes.